# How to pass a Bundle to another object (limited to AsyncTask Thread)?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to create a Bundle object for AsyncTask thread which remains **unaffected by changes** done to `data` (after passing it to `sendMessage()`.
My code immediately removes a value in `data` after calling `sendMessage()` but I need that value to be sent to server.
Can someone suggest an efficient way, such that once `data` is passed (it gets copied, for the lack of better term) for the duration of sending message and gets destroyed on its own.

CODE

```
public void sendMessage(final Bundle data)
{
    sendTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
            try
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "message_id: " + id);
                gcm.send(PROJECT_NUMBER + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "GCM send is a success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            sendTask = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "Result = " + result);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    sendTask.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to `doInBackground()`, here are the steps:

- Change parameter type accepted by AsyncTask `sendTask = new AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, String>()`
- Now change `protected String doInBackground(Void... params)` to protected String doInBackground(Bundle... params)
- You can access bundle using `gcm.send(PROJECT_NUMBER + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, params[0]);`
- Also change `sendTask.execute();` to `sendTask.execute(data);` for passing it to Async Task.

Comment: Yes, I know but i want know to whether this method make params[0] immune to any changes done to `data` or not?